# How do I get back files after "mv * .*"?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, mv

I hid some files using the command:

```
mv * .*
```

but now I am unable to find them. I tried using:

```
mv .* *
```

but nothing happened (an error was shown). If I run:

```
ls -la
```

it's showing:

```
total 8  
drwxrwxr-x 2 abhishek abhishek 4096 Mar  9 20:46 .  
drwxrwxr-x 4 abhishek abhishek 4096 Mar  9 20:46 ..
```

Is there any way to recover my hidden files?

Comment: The key thing here is that the glob stars `*` are processed before `mv` ever gets the chance to look at the command line. You can use `$ echo mv .* *` to preview the command line before running it, so you can see what `mv` sees.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Your files are not hidden, you have moved all files (and directories if any) one directory up.**

This happens because `mv * .*` won't work as you think it will. The command `mv` will only move one file to one file (rename) or move one or multiple files to a directory. It won't move multiple files to multiple files with some smart renaming.

---

**What happened?**

Let's assume we have one directory and 3 files in our directory:

```
dir1
file1
file2
file3
```

Some Shells (e.g. `bash`, `dash`, ...) will expand your command to:

```
mv dir1 file1 file2 file3 . ..
```

Your expanded command fits the second form of the SYNOPSIS you find at `man mv`:

> `mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY`

Note the `.` and `..`:

- `.` is the current directory,
- `..` is one directory up.

The command means: move `dir1`, `file1`, `file2` and `file3` and `.` to `..`; It will also essentially give an error, something like:

```
mv: cannot move '.' to '../.'
```

But given you have write permission in that directory, all other files have been moved. You can find your files in `..` (= one directory up). However, files with same name have been overwritten and you won't know which files was in which directory before.

---

If you had a subdirectory `.hidden-dir`, it would have expanded to:

```
mv dir1 file1 file2 file3 . .. .hidden-dir
```

Then, all files would have been moved to `.hidden-dir`. However, this seems not the case for you, because the you would have seen `.hidden-dir` in your `ls -la` output.

---

**How to fix**

Run:

```bsh
mv ../dir1 ../file1 ../file2 ../file3 .
```

However, you need to know the names.

---

**What you should have used**

```bsh
mmv '*' '.#1'
```

or

```bsh
rename 's/^/./' *
```

Comment: *and you won't know which files was in which directory before.* - all the files that were moved will have the same `ctime` - `ls -a -lcrt` is useful to sort files by ctime with the most recent ones at the bottom.

Comment: It *might* have moved one directory up.  It will move to whatever directory shows up last in the expansion of `.*`, which might some hidden directory, especially if this was done in a user's home directory or a directory under version control.  I would recommend running `ls -1d | tail -n1` in that directory.  (in this case, he had an otherwise empty directory ... but others might not be so fortunate)

Comment: True, I added that information to the question. However, it is not the case here as OP issued `ls -la` without output.

Comment: Shell also matters. For example, zsh doesn't match files `..` nor `.` for any glob.

Comment: Thanks, also added that it only happens for some shells

Comment: Note that `mmv` and `rename` may not be available everywhere. It would also probably be a good thing to emphasise the fact it`s `mmv` and not `mv` for the hurried reader .

Comment: `for x in *; do mv -i "$x" ".$x"; done`.

Comment: @spectras this will work if people have neither `mmv` or `rename`. However, at least `rename` is installed by default in Ubuntu and will be a lot faster for many files, as your loop will invoke `mv` for each file separately.

Comment: We are talking microseconds on a command you would run a few times a month at most, I really doubt that is relevant…